# Featured Posts Carousel on Tumblr

Tags: carousel, tumblr, zurb-foundation

I'm building a site on Tumblr that includes a carousel for featured posts. My Javascript skills are pretty limited, but it seemed like it should be straightforward. I've built custom themes with featured posts before, just nothing that used a carousel.

Since I'm already using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), I figured I could just use Orbit. I couldn't get that working and it was a little much for what I was trying to do, so I tried [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/). I'm still fighting with it.

I know there are a few themes out there that do something similar, but I was wondering if there was a simple solution—pull posts tagged "featured" from the RSS and drop it into a simple carousel—before going in and hacking at someone else's code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the RSS and not the API?

Comment: Whichever works, really. The last time I set up featured posts, RSS was the go-to method. I haven't done much with the API, but that's probably better.